# How to autoscale the yrange of gnuplot in python

Tags: gnuplot

I have a python script that I write out a .gnu file and it plots a .png file. I am trying to make the yrange more dynamic by setting the range to be 5% of the max and min.

What am I doing wrong?

This code will not run like this.

```
#-- write out .gnu file
    self.output = textwrap.dedent('''\
    set terminal png size 800,600 
    set output "{0}" 
    set grid 
    set xlabel "Cycle" 
    set title "{1}" 
    set xtics ({2})
    set yrange[GPVAL_Y_MIN:GPVAL_Y_MAX]
    plot ''').format(self.figurename, self.title, ",".join(plot_data.keys()), self.styletype, self.datafile)

    for n in range(0,max_num_lines):
        tmp_str = " ".join(['"{2}"','using','1:'+str(n+2),'title',"'"+self.titles[n+1]+"'",'w linespoints {1}']).format(self.figurename, self.linecombos[n], self.datafile)
        if n!=max(range(0,max_num_lines)):
            tmp_str += ", "
        self.output += tmp_str

    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The internal variables `GPVAL_Y_MIN`/`GPVAL_Y_MAX` are not initialized until you actually plot something. To circumvent this, you might use the `stats` command which analyzes a file and provides the desired min/max values via the `STATS_min_y`/`STATS_max_y` variables:

```
self.output = textwrap.dedent('''\
set terminal png size 800,600 
set output "{0}" 
set grid 
set xlabel "Cycle" 
set title "{1}" 
set xtics ({2})

#analyze the file and adjust y-range
stats "{3}" nooutput
set yrange[STATS_min_y:STATS_max_y]

plot ''').format(self.figurename, self.title, ",".join(plot_data.keys()), self.styletype, self.datafile)
```